# How to use custom display using pivot query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I currently have this query using PIVOT generating a table like this:

```
Name |Total |01-10-2014  |02-10-2014    
dd   |500   | 300        |200    
bb   |400   | 200        |200    
ff   |150   | 100        |50
```

Query is like this

```
select * from (
   select 
      COALESCE(RNAME, 'NO NAME') as Name,
      Total,
      CONVERT(varchar(10), date1,105) as Date,
      BILLAMT 
   from #temp 
   where date1 >= '2014-10-01' and date1 <= '2014-10-02'
) as D 
PIVOT(SUM(BILLAMT) for Date in ([01-10-2014],[02-10-2014])) as P
```

i need to `order by RNAME`. and **the total on right end** .. Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: sorted the answer by adding "order by NAME ASC" @ the end of the query. :)

Comment: so you no longer have a question? your problem is solved?

Comment: no. 1st issue is solved. i need to display the total field @ right end . am not able to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the column list then try this else you need to change this into dynamic pivot.

```
SELECT Name,
       [01-10-2014],
       [02-10-2014],
       Total
FROM   (SELECT COALESCE(RNAME, 'NO NAME')       AS Name,
               Total,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date1, 105) AS Date,
               BILLAMT
        FROM   #temp
        WHERE  date1 >= '2014-10-01'
               AND date1 <= '2014-10-02') AS D
       PIVOT(Sum(BILLAMT)
            FOR Date IN ([01-10-2014],
                         [02-10-2014])) AS P
ORDER  BY Name
```